# Custom FilePath in VB 2008 .Net coding

Tags: .net, vb.net, filepath

I just started working with VB .net 2008 a few months back, on and off, I've done a few tutorials and watched videos, however I'm confused on something.

I've noticed that in all codes that I've seen, there is a "FilePath" string like so:

```
Private MyFilePath As String = "c:\Temp\Database.xml"
```

How do you allow the user to set this save location (And File Name) for their database (be it xml, access or sql, etc.), OR am I misunderstanding the FilePath string completely?

I don't like to require my databases (or any files) to be in a certain location, but would rather have the user choose where to save them. Like with regular text files you can save wherever you want to, however a AAA game will save all gamesaves to MyDocuments/Games/GameName/GameSaves (This is not what I want to do, like the game saves.)

I've looked at a few tutorial on this, but still confused.

I'm I completely misunderstanding the concept of the "FilePath" string?

---

I will need this for my own database program that I'm working, and would like to learn more about it if I'm misunderstanding it.

Comment: MyFilePath is not something special, is just a mere string variable (the fact of writing the private statement does not change that). When an external file is required for any function, its path (what defines it) is usually provided via string (Dim thisString As String = "c:\Temp\Database.xml" would also do the job); logically you can change this variable as much as required. In any case, from your whole question, it seems to me that your ideas (in general, about VB.NET at least) are too unclear and that this is not the place where you can clear them up (you should keep learning)...

Comment: ... at least, this is my opinion, perhaps you are lucky and this question gets quite a few answers (happened a while ago with another question I thought that wasn't meant for SO; because of minimal understanding and stuff).

Comment: `would rather have the user choose`:  you are better off using one of the User AppData folders (designed for the purpose of...well, App Data_, your user might choose a location your app doesnt have sufficient permissions for.

Comment: See if this helps you: [Managing Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx)